# window.open function in HREF TAG not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to open popup using window.open finction but somehow it's not working ... well below is the code

```
string properties = "left=250px, top=245px, width=700px, height=450px,scrollbars=yes, status=yes, resizable=yes";
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Text = "<a href=\"javascript:void(window.open('details.aspx?node="+node+"','"+properties+"'))\">" + "View Details</a>";
```

But his is not working. While clicking the anchor tag getting javascript error "Invalid argument". Please tell where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: I see you have some questions with no accepted answer. Please go back to your previous questions and accept any good answers (green tick-mark next to the vote count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Never put JavaScript into the href attribute. This is how you should do it:

```
<a href="details.aspx?..." onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mypopup'); return false;">View Details</a>
```

I added the second argument for `window.open` (the window identifier) as well, which is probably what was breaking your thing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[How about using the target attribute on the anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) as in: <a href=”http://google.com”  target="_blank">Link text here </a>

[Anchor target attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

> - _blank – Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
> - _parent – Opens the linked document in the parent frame
> - _self – Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
> - _top – Opens the linked document in the full body of the window

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="?i=1" id ="a" runat = "server">

on Page_load()
if (Request.QueryString["i"] == "1")
{
//call ur code here
AreaFootPrint_Click(null,null);
}
```